# Two Criteria in on jsf page

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a jsf page with two query components with following view criterias:

- `VC1` and two bind variabe `a`**(required)** and `b`,
- `VC2` and two bind variable `c`**(required)** and `d`

Both applied to the same instance of viewObject and `rendered` property of both queries change with a pageFlowScope parameter

When I apply `VC2` view criteria and press **search** button an error appears: `The attribute a(from VC1) is required`

Whats the solution?

Comment: The solution can only be given when the logic is known. However, the logic in your question is incomplete, so a solution cannot be given. The logic didn't explicitly cover the relationship between VC1 and VC2. For example "a is not required if c is specified or vice versa", or "VC2 is not required when VC1 is fully specified", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Required parameter is required to be set, even if not used.
So you either have to set it with some value or remove *require* restriction.
In most cases ViewCriteria parameters shouldn't have *require* property set. And this is default behavior for such parameters in 12c. I assume you using some of 11g releases.

*But may be you trying to solve your problem in a wrong way? If it is the case, give us more details on your problem, you trying to solve.*

Comment: I found a way to handle this problem and I dont know even it is good or not
,in queryListener of VC2, I added below codes: 
        ViewCriteriaManager vm = MyVO.getViewCriteriaManager();
        ViewCriteria v = vm.getViewCriteria("VC2");
        v.clear();

Comment: @Sanaz I doubt you really want this to do. VC should not filter any results anymore since it become empty.

Comment: oh, sry! I made a mistake in writing!
i did this:
in queryListener of VC2, I added below codes: ViewCriteriaManager vm = MyVO.getViewCriteriaManager(); ViewCriteria v = vm.getViewCriteria("VC1"); v.clear();

Comment: @Sanaz its just the same, try to reapply VC1 criteria, it shouldn't filter any records anymore. I just don't get it, what are you trying to achieve and why you won't follow recommended way? Disable required property for your view criteria's parameters, it shouldn't be there. Required is for `WHERE clause` mostly.